# Toshiba Mini Netbook not turning on

Tags: windows-xp, boot, netbook

This is the second time this has happened with my Toshiba Mini Netbook. When I restart it, it will shut down but then not come back up. It seems like it's running but the screen is blank and the power button is lit. The first time it happened I shut it down via the power button, then turned it back on while pressing F2 and it came up properly. Now, however, it is not doing it. The screen remains blank. What could be causing this and how do I fix it? It is running Windows XP.

Comment: =/ Might be faulty.. still under warranty?

Comment: Yes it is. I purchased it from Best Buy. Do you think they could replace it, but save all the hard drive information?

Comment: Do you have a usb disk? If you do you can backup all your information on that. I just got an 8GB usb disk for about $18 on amazon.

Another option is to buy an external hard drive, or even an external hard drive enclosure, and back up your data to that.

Comment: Probably should back up my data more often, but the problem here is that I can't get it to start up yet. Is there a way to back up the computer without it properly starting up?

Comment: do you have another computer to work with? If so you can make a linux live cd to back it up.

Comment: Linux? My other laptop runs Windows XP. How would a Linix Live CD work?

Comment: You pop in the CD and it runs Linux from the CD without changing anything on your harddrive. You can also do it from a USB disk..

Answer (score 1):

Drain the 'flea power':

disconnect the AC power adapter, remove the battery and press the power button for a few seconds.

*I'm not familiar with the Toshiba, but ASUS Eee PC do have a reset button (a small hole at the bottom of the case, accessible with a pin).*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What exactly does the reset button do? Will I lose any of my data?

Comment: no, data on the hard disk drive will not be affected by using the reset button.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too a few times on my TOSHIBA netbook. I unplugged it, pulled the battery for about 10 secs, and then put it back in. Hasn't happened since. I am running Windows 7 Starter.